# can i build c++ code for different platforms(like stm32 ARM processor) in visual studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

Can i compile a c++ code in visual studio 2012 IDE which will be ultimately run on a stm32 ARM processor. Because i think visual studio is the best when it comes to IDE in the current time. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Yes if you buy the right tools. There are two that I know of: WinGDB at http://www.wingdb.com/
and VisualGDB at http://visualgdb.com/. Looks like they will let you use Visual Studio and use either a GCC cross-compiler or GCC running on a remote to do the actual compilation.

Comment: You don't need to buy any tools to do that. Visual Studio already comes with the ability to have makefile projects, which allow you to use any compiler / build system you like behind the scenes. I am currently working on a project with Visual Studio as my IDE, SCons as my build system, and both MSVC and MinGW as compilers.

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no. Visual Studio can target multiple Windows platforms, including Windows on ARM. But it can't target Linux on ARM, which is by far the most common.

Comment: Then we need to use other third party cross compiler to build for such platform on window machine right?

Comment: Yes, but it might be easier to build on Linux. You can still develop on Windows, though.

Comment: @Jnana Don't confuse compiler with IDE though. You can use any compiler you like, but still use Visual Studio as your IDE (albeit with some extra set up work, using makefile projects).

Comment: @JBentley Thanks ya ya you are absolutely right. Sorry if i confuse you but my intension was not that.